# Spring Boot, filtered OneToMany(mappedBy)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have these two entities:

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<UserBook> userBookList;
}
```

And

```
public class UserBook {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private Book book;

    @Column(name = "page_read")
    private int pageRead;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to retrieve the list of books from by postgre database and inject into  *userBookList* (for every books) the object from the related UserBook entity **given the current user** that is sending the request. As of now, every time I get a list of books, userBookList would contain every item inside the UserBook table related to his specific book.

Is there a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So what you have above is bi-directional mapping. If you take userBookList, it has multiple UserBooks referring to a book. If you just want a clean JSON output without circular referring, then add @JsonIgnore to the one you dont want to be repeated.

Comment: @Loris did this work?, if so you can accept my answer which will increase your chances to get answers